# Rearranging tblr within a tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray

This is the current version:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                babel,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadings, shapes.geometric,
                3d}
\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    my angle/.style = {draw, font=\small,
                       angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm},
    base/.style = {draw, thick},
    dashline/.style = {densely dashed, very thick},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner sep=1pt, font=\small},
    Trapezium/.style = {base, trapezium,
                        trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120,
                        minimum width=30mm}
        }
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{fonttitle=\Large\bfseries, coltitle=white, colback=white,
        colframe=black,nobeforeafter,
        sidebyside, sidebyside gap=3mm,
        lower separated=true,
        sharp corners
        }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title]
\begin{tblr}{%width=0.49\textwidth,
             hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math]
                        Q[c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Drawing 1 &   &   \\
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &
        \tikz{[scale=0.2
]
\def\a{1.5}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
\coordinate (C) at (0,\a); 
\coordinate (D) at (\a,\a); 
\draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
\path (A) -- node [midway,below] {\scriptsize a} (B);
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
Circumference
        &   u=4\cdot a &
        \tikz{[scale=0.2
]
\def\a{1.5}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
\coordinate (C) at (0,\a); 
\coordinate (D) at (\a,\a); 
\draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
\path (A) -- node [midway,below] {\scriptsize a} (B);}   \\
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\tcblower                   % right side of box
\begin{tblr}{%width=0.49\textwidth,
             hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math]
                        Q[c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Drawing 2 &   &   \\
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &
        \tikz{  [scale=0.2,very thick
]
\def\a{3}
\def\b{1}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
\coordinate (C) at (0,\b); 
\coordinate (D) at (\a,\b); 
\draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
\path (A) -- node [midway,below] {\scriptsize a} (B);
\path (B) -- node [midway,right] {\scriptsize b} (D);
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
Circumference
        &   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &
        \tikz{  [scale=0.2,very thick
]
\def\a{3}
\def\b{1}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
\coordinate (C) at (0,\b); 
\coordinate (D) at (\a,\b); 
\draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
\path (A) -- node [midway,below] {\scriptsize a} (B);
\path (B) -- node [midway,right] {\scriptsize b} (D);
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\begin{tblr}{%width=0.49\textwidth,
             hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math]
                        Q[c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Drawing 3 &   &   \\
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &
        \tikz{  [my angle/.style={font=\small, draw, angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm},very thick]
  \node (a) [trapezium, trapezium angle=50, minimum width=30mm, draw, very thick, label=above:\scriptsize c, label=below:\scriptsize a, label=right:\scriptsize b, label=left:\scriptsize d] {};
  \draw [densely dashed] (a.north west) coordinate (a nw) -- (a nw |- a.south) node [midway,right] {$\scriptstyle h$} ;
 % \draw (a nw |- a.south) ++(0,1.5mm) -| ++(-1.5mm,-1.5mm) (a ne |- a.south) +%+(0,1.5mm) -| ++(1.5mm,-1.5mm);
  \coordinate (a blc) at (a.bottom left corner);
  \coordinate (a brc) at (a.bottom right corner);
  %\pic [my angle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=a1--a blc--a nw};
  %\pic [my angle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=a ne--a brc--a1};
  %\pic [my angle, "$\beta$"] {angle=a blc--a nw--a1};
  %\pic [my angle, "$\beta$"] {angle=a2--a ne--a brc};
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
Circumference
        &   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &
        \tikz{  [my angle/.style={font=\small, draw, angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm},very thick]
  \node (a) [trapezium, trapezium angle=50, minimum width=30mm, draw, very thick, label=above:\scriptsize c, label=below:\scriptsize a, label=right:\scriptsize b, label=left:\scriptsize d] {};
  %\draw [densely dashed] (a.north west) coordinate (a nw) -- (a nw |- a.south) node [midway,right] {$\scriptstyle h$} ;
 % \draw (a nw |- a.south) ++(0,1.5mm) -| ++(-1.5mm,-1.5mm) (a ne |- a.south) +%+(0,1.5mm) -| ++(1.5mm,-1.5mm);
  \coordinate (a blc) at (a.bottom left corner);
  \coordinate (a brc) at (a.bottom right corner);
  %\pic [my angle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=a1--a blc--a nw};
  %\pic [my angle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=a ne--a brc--a1};
  %\pic [my angle, "$\beta$"] {angle=a blc--a nw--a1};
  %\pic [my angle, "$\beta$"] {angle=a2--a ne--a brc};
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{%width=0.49\textwidth,
             hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math]
                        Q[c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Drawing 4 &   &   \\
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \draw [dashline] (a.north west)  to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
                \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
Circumference
        &   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \path   (a.top left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom left corner)
                        (a.bottom left corner)  to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);;
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the following arrangement:
[image]

Addendum:
Do you know how to fix the width of the boxes, such that Drawing 1 can be as wide as Drawing 2-4?

Comment: You should explicitly state the width of the columns to ensure that the columns in all four tabulars have the same width. You can do this using the `wd` option, for example using `Q[c, wd=3cm]`. I would probably create some custom template or macro to avoid repetition of the code. It is not clear to me, though, how you would like the four tabulars to be arranged: One on the left and three on the right, or (like presented in the picture) two on the left and two on the right?

Comment: If you have suggestions for improvements, please feel free! Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: `\tikz{[scale=0.2]` is wrong syntax. Either use `\tikz[scale=0.2]{` or remove `[scale=0.2]` completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to place two tabulars to the right and two to the left in the `tcolorbox`, you need to place two `tblr` environments before `\tcblower` and the other two after `\tcblower`. Currently, you've got only one before `\tcblower`.

Apart from that, I've got a few suggestions (which also solve the question about the width of the tabulars):

- Create your custom `tblr` environment in order to avoid repetition of code. The same holds for the Ti*k*Z styles you use. You can even define the required column spans already for this environment.
- In order not to get too wide tabulars, I would put "Area" and "Circumference" in another row and span the relevant cell over two columns. You should also remove the empty last row in each of the tables.
  -- You should probably explicitly set the height and width of the cells (using the `ht` and `wd` options) to make the appearance of the four tabulars equal.
- I would stick to a unified syntax in the Ti*k*Z drawings to make sure that they really look alike: You use `to["$a$"]` in the last diagram, so why not using this way of placing the labels in the other diagrams as well?
- `\tikz{[scale=0.2] ...` is not the right syntax. You need to place the global options in front of the opening curly brace (like `\tikz[scale=0.2]{ ...`. But in fact, it is not necessary to use such options here at all.

The full MWE including the above suggestions and some other improvements:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
    baseline = (current bounding box.center),
    base/.style = {
        draw, 
        very thick
    },
    dashline/.style = {
        densely dashed, 
        very thick
    },
    every edge quotes/.style = {
        auto = right, 
        font = \small
    },
    TrapeziumA/.style = {
        base, 
        trapezium, 
        trapezium angle=50, 
        minimum width=30mm
    },
    TrapeziumB/.style = {
        base, 
        trapezium,
        trapezium left angle = 60, 
        trapezium right angle = 120,
        minimum width = 30mm
    }
}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    fonttitle = \Large\bfseries, 
    coltitle = white, 
    colback = white,
    colframe = black,
    nobeforeafter,
    sidebyside, 
    sidebyside gap = 3mm,
    lower separated = true,
    sharp corners
}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{
    hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, 
    vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
    hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
    colspec = {Q[l, wd=0.5cm, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
               Q[l, wd=3.25cm, bg=gray!10, mode=math]
               Q[c, wd=3.75cm]},
    colsep = 3pt,
    row{1} = {bg = gray!30},
    row{odd[3-Z]} = {ht = 2cm},
    cell{1}{1} = {c = 3}{l},
    cell{even}{1} = {c = 2}{l}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[title = Title]
\centering
\begin{mytblr}{}
Drawing 1 & & \\
Area & & \\
 & A = a^2
 & \tikz{
    \def\a{1.5}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\a); 
    \coordinate (D) at (\a,\a); 
    \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \path (A) to["$a$"] (B);
} \\
Circumference & & \\
 & u = 4 \cdot a 
 & \tikz{
    \def\a{1.5}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\a); 
    \coordinate (D) at (\a,\a); 
    \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \path (A) to["$a$"] (B);
} \\
\end{mytblr}
\begin{mytblr}{}
Drawing 2 & & \\
Area & & \\
 & A = a \cdot b
 & \tikz{
    \def\a{3}
    \def\b{1}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\b); 
    \coordinate (D) at (\a,\b); 
    \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \path (A) to["$a$"] (B);
    \path (B) to["$b$"] (D);
}  \\
Circumference & & \\
 & u = 2 \cdot a + 2 \cdot b 
 & \tikz{
    \def\a{3}
    \def\b{1}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\b); 
    \coordinate (D) at (\a,\b); 
    \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \path (A) to["$a$"] (B);
    \path (B) to["$b$"] (D);
} \\
\end{mytblr}
\tcblower % right side of box
\centering
\begin{mytblr}{}
Drawing 3 & & \\
Area & & \\
 & A = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (a + c) \cdot h 
 & \tikz{
    \node (a) [TrapeziumA] {};
    \path (a.bottom left corner) to["$a$"] (a.bottom right corner)
          (a.bottom right corner) to["$b$"] (a.top right corner)
          (a.top left corner) to["$c$" '] (a.top right corner)
          (a.top left corner) to["$d$"] (a.bottom left corner);
    \draw[dashline] (a.north west) to["$h$" '] (a.north west |- a.south);
} \\
Circumference & & \\
 & u = a + b + c + d 
 & \tikz{
    \node (a) [TrapeziumA] {};
    \path (a.bottom left corner) to["$a$"] (a.bottom right corner)
          (a.bottom right corner) to["$b$"] (a.top right corner)
          (a.top left corner) to["$c$" '] (a.top right corner)
          (a.top left corner) to["$d$"] (a.bottom left corner);
}  \\
\end{mytblr}
\begin{mytblr}{}
Drawing 4 & & \\
Area & & \\
 & A = g \cdot h 
 & \tikz{
    \node (a) [TrapeziumB] {};
    \draw[dashline] (a.north west) to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
    \path (a.bottom left corner) to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);
} \\
Circumference & & \\
 & u = 2 \cdot a + 2 \cdot b 
 & \tikz{
    \node (a) [TrapeziumB] {};
    \path (a.top left corner) to["$a$"] (a.bottom left corner)
          (a.bottom left corner) to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);
} \\
\end{mytblr}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @Jasper Habicht answer, but tables are without multirow cells and `tikzpicture`s with wee bit modified styles for `\tikzpicture`s from my answer on OP previous question:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric,
                }
\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    my angle/.style = {draw, font=\small,
                       angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm},
    base/.style = {draw, thick},
    dashline/.style = {densely dashed, very thick},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner sep=1pt, font=\small},
    Rect/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, minimum height=#1, minimum width=#2},
    Trap/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, trapezium,
                        trapezium left angle=#1, trapezium right angle=#2,
                        minimum width=30mm}
        }
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{fonttitle=\Large\bfseries, coltitle=white, colback=white,
        colframe=cyan,nobeforeafter,
        sidebyside, sidebyside gap=3mm,
        lower separated=false
        }

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr} % <--- added by @Jasper Habicht
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{             
    hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
    hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
    colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
               X[c, bg=gray!10]
               Q[c, wd=33mm]},
    colsep  = 3pt,
    cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{l},
    cell{odd[3]}{1} = {c=2}{c, fg=red, mode=math},
    row{1}  = {bg=gray!30, mode=text},
    row{2-Z}= {belowsep=4pt},
    row{odd[3-Z]} = {ht = 19mm}
                      }

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[title = Title]
    \begin{mytblr}{}
    Drawing             &   &   \\
    Area                &   &   \\
    A=a\cdot a = a^2    &   &   
            \tikz{\node (a) [Rect=13mm/13mm] {};
                  \path (a.south west)  to["$a$"] (a.south east)
                        (a.south east)  to["$a$"] (a.north east);
                }   \\
    Circumference       &   &   \\
   u=4\cdot a           &   &   
            \tikz{\node (a) [Rect=13mm/13mm] {};
                  \path (a.south west)  to["$a$"] (a.south east)
                        (a.south east)  to["$a$"] (a.north east);
                }   \\
    \end{mytblr}
    
\medskip
    \begin{mytblr}{}
    Drawing             &   &   \\
    Area                &   &   \\
    A=a\cdot b          &   &   
            \tikz{\node (a) [Rect=13mm/26mm] {};
                  \path (a.south west)  to["$a$"] (a.south east)
                        (a.south east)  to["$b$"] (a.north east);
                }   \\
    Circumference       &   &   \\
    u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &   &   
           \tikz{\node (a) [Rect=13mm/26mm] {};
                  \path (a.south west)  to["$a$"] (a.south east)
                        (a.south east)  to["$b$"] (a.north east);
                }   \\
    \end{mytblr}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\tcblower % right side of box
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{mytblr}{}
    Drawing             &   &   \\
    Area                &   &   \\
    A=g\cdot h          &   &   
            \tikz{\node (a) [Trap=60/120] {};
                  \draw [dashline] (a.north west)  to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
                  \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);
                }   \\
    Circumference       &   &   \\
   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b  &   &   \
            \tikz{\node (a) [Trap=60/120] {};
                  \path   (a.top left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom left corner)
                          (a.bottom left corner)  to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);;
                }   \\
    \end{mytblr}
    
\medskip    
    \begin{mytblr}{}
    Drawing                     &   &   \\
    Area                        &   &   \\
    A=\frac{1}{2}(a+c)\cdot h   &   & 
            \tikz{\node (a) [Trap=60/60] {};
                  \draw [dashline] (a.north west)  to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
                  \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom right corner)
                          (a.bottom right corner)  to["$b$"] (a.top right corner)
                          (a.top right corner)  to["$c$"] (a.top left corner)
                          (a.top left corner)  to["$d$"] (a.bottom left corner);
                }   \\
    Circumference           &   &   \\
   u=a+b+c+d                &   &   
            \tikz{\node (a) [Trap=60/60] {};
                  \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom right corner)
                          (a.bottom right corner)  to["$b$"] (a.top right corner)
                          (a.top right corner)  to["$c$"] (a.top left corner)
                          (a.top left corner)  to["$d$"] (a.bottom left corner);
                }   \\
    \end{mytblr}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution. There is one issue:
If I place a fifth inner box on the left hand side, the inner box on the right hand side is not placed at the upper part of the outer box. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: How can I add a normal text to an inner box? Due to mode=math it is not that easy to have a normal text and a mathematical expression. 
Furthermore, could you show how to add a multiline formula like
\begin{align*}
u&=2\cdot \pi \cdot r\\
  &=\pi\cdot d
\end{align*}

Comment: @KevinC, where you like to add text? INstead of existed equations? Multiline equation you can add as you wrote in comment. I suggest you to address your comment to author of accepted answer   or even better ask new question.

Comment: For example in the rectangle inner box. (second row, first column):

The Circumference is given by
 u=2\cdot a +2\cdot b

OK. I am confused that a multiline construction would work with \begin{align} environment. This would be a math mode within a math mode.
I address the author, but "@username“ is always deleted.

Comment: @KevinC, again, as I see, you not use my answer, but another. So you need help from author of accepted answer :-). An kake my suggestion to write new question seriously. This site is not a forum. New problem, new question ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a not finished proposal. Like previous answer it uses a `tcolorbox` but all the structure is organized using `tcboxedraster`. Every `Drawing` is also a `boxedraster` which contains two boxes, one for `area` and one for `circumference`. Each boxes is a `bicolor, sidebyside` with a `tikz lower` option.

The not finished part is how to force the equal height to the lower row. I need some more time to solve them, if it's possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, shapes.geometric}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\tikzset{
    baseline = (current bounding box.center),
    base/.style = {
        draw, 
        very thick
    },
    dashline/.style = {
        densely dashed, 
        very thick
    },
    every edge quotes/.style = {
        auto = right, 
        font = \small
    },
    TrapeziumA/.style = {
        base, 
        trapezium, 
        trapezium angle=50, 
        minimum width=30mm
    },
    TrapeziumB/.style = {
        base, 
        trapezium,
        trapezium left angle = 60, 
        trapezium right angle = 120,
        minimum width = 30mm
    }
}

\tcbset{
    outerraster/.style={raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows},
    outerrasterstyle/.style={sharp corners, fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries, title=#1, colback=yellow!10, top=1mm, left=1mm, right=1mm, bottom=1mm},
    drawingraster/.style={raster columns=1, sharp corners, raster row skip=-0.25pt,},
    drawingrasterstyle/.style={sharp corners, colbacktitle=black!30, title=Drawing~\thetcbrasternum, coltitle=black, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, enhanced,},
    drawingbox/.style={enhanced, bicolor, sidebyside, tikz lower, boxrule=0.5pt, 
        raster odd row/.style={overlay={\node[anchor=north west, outer sep=1mm, font=\bfseries] at (frame.north west) {Area};}},
        raster even row/.style={overlay={\node[anchor=north west, outer sep=1mm, font=\bfseries] at (frame.north west) {Circumference};}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[outerraster]{outerrasterstyle=Main title}
\tcbitem[blankest]
%Drawing 1
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[drawingraster, drawingbox]{drawingrasterstyle}
\tcbitem
\[A = a^2\]
\tcblower     
    \def\a{1.5}
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
   \coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
   \coordinate (C) at (0,\a); 
   \coordinate (D) at (\a,\a); 
   \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
   \path (A) to["$a$"] (B);
\tcbitem \[u = 4 \cdot a\] 
\tcblower 
    \def\a{1.5}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\a); 
    \coordinate (D) at (\a,\a); 
    \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \path (A) to["$a$"] (B);
\end{tcboxeditemize}

%Drawing 2
\tcbitem[blankest]
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[drawingraster, drawingbox]{drawingrasterstyle}
\tcbitem \[A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot(a+c)\cdot h\]
\tcblower     
    \node (a) [TrapeziumA] {};
    \path (a.bottom left corner) to["$a$"] (a.bottom right corner)
          (a.bottom right corner) to["$b$"] (a.top right corner)
          (a.top left corner) to["$c$" '] (a.top right corner)
          (a.top left corner) to["$d$"] (a.bottom left corner);
    \draw[dashline] (a.north west) to["$h$" '] (a.north west |- a.south);

\tcbitem \[u = a+b+c+d\] 
\tcblower 
    \node (a) [TrapeziumA] {};
    \path (a.bottom left corner) to["$a$"] (a.bottom right corner)
          (a.bottom right corner) to["$b$"] (a.top right corner)
          (a.top left corner) to["$c$" '] (a.top right corner)
          (a.top left corner) to["$d$"] (a.bottom left corner);
\end{tcboxeditemize}

%Drawing 3
\tcbitem[blankest]
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[drawingraster, drawingbox]{drawingrasterstyle}
\tcbitem \[A = a\cdot b\]
\tcblower     
    \def\a{3}
    \def\b{1}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\b); 
    \coordinate (D) at (\a,\b); 
    \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \path (A) to["$a$"] (B);
    \path (B) to["$b$"] (D);

\tcbitem \[u = 2\cdot a+2\cdot b\] 
\tcblower 
    \def\a{3}
    \def\b{1}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (\a,0) ;
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\b); 
    \coordinate (D) at (\a,\b); 
    \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \path (A) to["$a$"] (B);
    \path (B) to["$b$"] (D);
\end{tcboxeditemize}

%Drawing 4
\tcbitem[blankest]
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[drawingraster, drawingbox]{drawingrasterstyle}
\tcbitem \[A = g\cdot h\]
\tcblower     
    \node (a) [TrapeziumB] {};
    \draw[dashline] (a.north west) to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
    \path (a.bottom left corner) to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);

\tcbitem \[u = 2\cdot a+2\cdot b\] 
\tcblower 
    \node (a) [TrapeziumB] {};
    \path (a.top left corner) to["$a$"] (a.bottom left corner)
          (a.bottom left corner) to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);
\end{tcboxeditemize}
\end{tcboxeditemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]